# How to set the timezone permanently in ubuntu using C program

Tags: c, date, datetime, ubuntu, timezone

When i write -

> root@XYZ:/home/timez# export TZ=UTC; date
>
> Thu Nov 13 05:35:36 UTC 2014

It change the date & timezone. I want a equivalent C program of this.

I wrote a C program to set Timezone in my Ubuntu machine using code -

> system(" export TZ=CST6CDT; date ");

i can see the date in CST as output but this program is not setting Ubuntu Timezone to CST, it is still in UTC.

Comment: Have you tried this ` export TZ=CST6CDT; date` command on terminal before entering into a C program? Did it work ?

Comment: the timezone info is kept in a file in ubuntu.  this file: /etc/default/rcS needs to be modified to indicate if UTC or local time is being used for the RTC.  then this link: /etc/localtime needs to be updated to point to the correct entry in this directory: /usr/share/zoneinfo/.  of course, by then you will have implemented the (already existing) tzconfig utility

Comment: @SantoshA Yes ofcourse, this command is working perfectly on terminal for any given timezone. But, not working through C program.

Comment: @user3629249 the tzconfig command is deprecated. I want to perform this task programmatically. ` export TZ=CST6CDT; date` command is working fine on terminal for any given timezone. But, not working through C program. I tried system(),exec() but it is not changing terminal date & timezone.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a `settimeofday` call inherited from Unix V7 or even before ... that used to set a time zone value in the kernel. But my current man says now :  *Note: timezone is no longer used; this information is kept outside the kernel*.

So in system less than 20 years old, the time zone is only kept in the environment. And the environment has the following property :

> a child inherit the environment of its parent but cannot modify its parent's environment

That means that any C program can modify its TZ via a simple `setenv` call, and this new timezone will be used by itself and all its childs, but it will never be able to modify the environment of the shell that started it. The only possibility would be a special API offered by shell programs, but I know none that implements such a thing.

I know it is a *you can't* answer but it is the best I can do ...